# Splitting a .txt file into a JavaScript Array using FileReader.readAsText()

Tags: javascript, arrays, filereader

I've used FileReader.readAsText() to import a file and import it into my array, but it creates a new array that ends up pushing into the first position of my existing array. When I try to index that array it apparently is "undefined" even though I can clearly see the value in my console.log command. My test .txt file reads

aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
ddd
eee
eee

I want to read the file and store it into an array by splitting each line
'''

```
        var guestList = []
        document.getElementById('inputfile') 
        .addEventListener('change', function loadFile() { 
          
        var fr=new FileReader(); 
        fr.onload=function(){ 
          guestList.push(fr.result.split('\n')); 
          
        } 
        console.log(guestList)
          
        fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
    }) 
    console.log(guestList)
```

'''
Here is what my console looks like:
[[]
0: (9) ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "ddd", "eee", "eee", ""]
length: 1
**proto**: Array(0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IozuX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only pushing a single item to the `guestList` - the result of splitting the file. Instead, just use the result of the `.split`, instead of surrounding it in another array - and make sure to log the results *inside* the callback, not outside.

Also, for multi-system compatibility, some environments use line feed characters as well as newlines. Consider using a regular expression instead, to optionally match a linefeed followed by a newline:

```
document.getElementById('inputfile').addEventListener('change', () => {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = () => {
    const guestList = fr.result.split(/\r?\n/);
    console.log(guestList);
  };
  fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
});
```